# Cleaning the back of LCD screen

Tags: cleaning, glass, hardware, repair, chemicals

I was asked to repaire LCD screen and after doing so, I wanted to polish the screen so I used ACETONE to clean it, but when I tried the same on the back of the LCD, acetone dried and don't know how to remove it.

[image: acetone stuck on the back of LCD]

I tried dish-washing product and clothes-washig product without success.

Question:

Kindly tell my how to remove this dried acetone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Catche.Me, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got some ***REALLY BAD ADVICE***.

You cannot remove the acetone. You have melted the plastic on the back of the screen. Acetone is a solvent for plastic.

If the area is very lightly affected, you may be able to hide the damage by using **CAR BODY PASTE WAX** as you would on a fine car finish. Car paste wax in a **LIGHT** application will fill the microscopically small pits in the plastic finish. Buffing the wax will probably make the dark finish on the back of the monitor look practically new.

The wax finish will not be as durable as the original plastic. Since it will sit facing away from viewers, it probably won't be noticed if you don't mention it. Car wax is tough and it should last as long as the monitor does.

You might have to buy a new case for the monitor or replace the whole monitor if your favour isn't appreciated by whomever you did this for.

Good luck.

Comment: I ended up with sanding the hole plastic, so equal amount of light would path :) and it is a low resolution screen, so won't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

You got some REALLY BAD ADVICE. (Alternate answer)

You cannot remove the acetone. You have melted the plastic on the back of the screen. Acetone is a solvent for plastic.

You can try to polish the rough plastic finish with a light abrasive such as jeweller's rouge or common toothpaste. Do this by hand. Do not take any short-cuts with power tools.

Search the Web for instructions to polish plastic. There is some instructions for polishing automobile headlight covers and for polishing convertible top windows. Use them for guidance and tips.

You might have to buy a new case for the monitor or replace the whole monitor if your favour isn't appreciated by whomever you did this for.

Good luck.